# Three20: Application failed codesign verification

Tags: iphone, three20, app-store-connect, codesign

I've just made an iPhone app which includes Three20 library. I have no problem with building & running the app on device. I have no error when I build the app for distribution but when I submit the app via ApplicationLoader, I get the error "Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate.". I don't think I have any mistake when building because I have built many apps for distribution with the same distribution certificate & provisioning. I tried with a simple app with Three20 included and I had the same issue. So I guess this kind of error may related to Three20. I also tried to change all projects of Three20 to distribution configuration, configure the same provisioning profile as in my main project, compile all these projects one by one and then build the main project, but ... NO LUCK :(

Answer (score 0):

**Private Key**

Do you have the private and public keys (both) in your KeyChain (ie. /Applications/Utilities/Keychain Access.app)? Note that the private and public keys are linked to the mobile provisioning profile (distribution) that you use to sign the binary in Xcode for app distribution. You need the mobile provisioning profile and private key for code signing.

Also, the private key is tied to your user account on the Mac. I believe the private key may be invalidated if you change your account name or reinstall the OS. Make sure you sign with they haven't expired (or revoked).

**Certificate Authority**

Make sure you have the Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority in your Keychain and the cert hasn't expired.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There's nothing wrong with the private/public keys or provisioning profile. After a day of struggling with this sucker problem without any success, I decided to recreate the project. Now it works just fine :) Bla bla ... I still don't know what the problem is :(